# Check if files exist in multiple directories using wildcards

Tags: linux, bash

I have ~10,000 directories. Most of them have a similarly named text file. 
I would like to take these .txt files and copy them to a folder in the main directory, ALL_RESULTS. How can i accomplish this? What I have below

```
for d in *_directories/; do

  #go into directory
  cd "$d"

  #check if file exists using wildcard, then copy it into ALL_RESULTS and print the name of 
  #directory out
  if ls *SCZ_PGC3_GWAS.sumstats.gz*.txt 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    cp *SCZ_PGC3_GWAS.sumstats.gz*.txt ../ALL_RESULTS && echo "$d"

  #if file does not exist, print the name of the directory we're 
  #in
  else
    echo "$d"
    echo "files do not exist"
  cd ..
  fi
done
```

I keep getting errors saying the directories themselves don't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying I should ```cd ../``` at the end of my loop?

Comment: Where you have `cd ..` now, you will only go back to the original directory if you didn't copy any files. That should be execute unconditionally, just like `cd "$d"` was.

Answer (score 1):

All relative paths are interpreted relative to the directory you are in (the "current working directory"). So, imagine, you cd into the first directory. So now you are in that directory. Then you loop executes, and you try to cd into the second directory. But that directory is no longer then, you need to go "up" and then cd into the directory. That is the reason the directory does not exists - you have to go "up" a directory for each directory you cd into.

So you need to `cd ..` on the end of your loop to go back to the directory you started from.

> I have ~10,000 directories. ... I would like to take these .txt files and move them to a folder in the main directory, ALL_RESULTS

If you don't need to output anything, just use `find` for that with a proper regex. Doing `ls` and `cd` and a loop will be very slow. Something along:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -regex '\./.*_directories/.*SCZ_PGC3_GWAS.sumstats.gz.*\.txt' -exec cp {} ALL_RESULTS \;
```

You can also add `-v` to `cp` to see what it copies.

Comment: I edited my code (adding cd), is this what you mean?

Comment: The `cd` has to be after `fi`, otherwise it will not execute if there are files.

Comment: I would like to know which directories have missing files. Is there a way to do that? (Hence the else statement in loop).

Answer (score -1):

You miss

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

and don't parse [ls](/questions/tagged/ls) output :

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for d in *_directories/; do
  # check if file exists using wildcard, then copy it into ALL_RESULTS and print
  # the name of directory
  files=$( $d/*SCZ_PGC3_GWAS.sumstats.gz*.txt )
  if [[ ${files[@]} ]]; then
    cp "${files[@]}" ALL_RESULTS && echo "$d"

  #if file does not exist, print the name of the directory we're 
  #in
  else
    echo "$d"
    echo "files do not exist"
  fi
done
```

Comment: The error from the op will persist - once you `cd "$d"`, you will not `cd` into the next directory. The `files=$(` should be array `files=(` and `if "${files[@]}"` tries to run a command, you mean `if [ "${#files[@]}" -ne 0 ]`

Comment: unfortunately still does not work, i get no output.

Comment: I definitely would not use `[[ ${files[@]} ]]`; just check the length of the array with `(( ${#files[@]} ))` instead.

Comment: What is the output of `bash -x script.sh` ?